# Htaccess root to /frontpage/

Tags: .htaccess, indexing, url-rewriting

How do i get my root to direct to /frontpage/ it doesnt have to load the content from there, because i have a rewrite url that looks like this

```
RewriteRule    ^Frontpage/?$    ?page=frontpage    [NC,L]
```

So really it has to load content from ?page=frontpage but show /frontpage/ when you enter the site. Is this possible, and how?

I have tried some things, but i seem to only be able to find rewrites where it loads from /frontpage/ but doesnt show it in the adress bar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have your rules like this:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+[\s?]
RewriteRule ^$ /frontpage/ [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^Frontpage/?$ ?page=frontpage [NC,QSA,L]
```

Comment: Srry, that doesnt really seem to work right here. It doesnt direct to /Frontpage

Comment: It does redirect to `/frontpage/` in my testing. Make sure you keep `R=301` rule as your first rule.